# Uploading to SQL Server using Microsoft Sync from SQL CE database

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I've searched around for this but am having some difficulty finding much information on successfully uploading changes FROM the SQL CE database to the SQL Server.

I have my synchronize function setup like:

```
public int Synchronize() {
    List<SyncOperationStatistics> syncStats = new List<SyncOperationStatistics>();

        // set the direction of sync session to 'Download' because ony the server can be modified.
    SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
    syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;

        foreach (var scopeName in ScopeNames) {
            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlCeSyncProvider(scopeName, DB_SqlCeConnection);
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, DB_SqlConnection);

            // subscribe for errors that occur when applying changes to the client
            ((SqlCeSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);
            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Remote_ApplyChangeField);

            SyncOperationStatistics syncStat = null;

            // execute the synchronization process                
            syncStat = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

            // Add synchronization statistics to list
            syncStats.Add(syncStat);
        }

        return syncStats.Count;
    }
```

With the `syncOrchestrator.Direction` set to `Upload`, I will receive the error of

```
Cannot enumerate changes at the RelationalSyncProvider for table 'table1'.
```

I am able to sync changes from the server to the CE database quite easily. Going in the other direction seems like a challenge.

Comment: Is this an error in the form of an Exception? Then please `edit` your question and supply the full stack trace.